# Difference between selections when using 'attr()'

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have piece of code which is invoked on a button click.

```
const lines = svg.select('lines').selectAll('line').data(arr);
lines.enter().append('line');
lines
  .attr('x1', d => d)
  .attr('y1', d => d)
  .attr('x2', d => d+2)
  .attr('y2', d => d+2)
  .attr('stroke-width', 2);
```

And when i click the button nothing shows up, but on clicking the button for the second time the lines could be seen.

So I tried chaining the **.attr()** to the **.append()** only.
Like this:

```
const lines = svg.select('lines').selectAll('line').data(arr);
    lines.enter().append('line')
      .attr('x1', d => d)
      .attr('y1', d => d)
      .attr('x2', d => d+2)
      .attr('y2', d => d+2)
      .attr('stroke-width', 2);
```

This time the lines could be seen on the first click of the button.

I just want to know the reason behind this behavior.

Comment: I changed your question's title for something easier to be found and referenced in the future (which is one of the main goals of S.O.), feel free to roll it back if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first code snippet, you are executing the `.attr` on the lines variable.  This is holding the `update` selection (a selection of those *things* already on the page).  Since nothing pre-exists, there is nothing to update.

In the second code snippet, you are executing the `.attr` on the *thing* returned by the `.append` method (via chaining).  Those *things* were just added to the page by `.enter` and are the `enter` selection.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Mark's (correct) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45088763/5768908), it's worth mentioning that this snippet of yours **will work** in D3 v3.x!

What happened is that Mike Bostock, D3 creator, introduced a *magic behaviour* in D3 v2, which he kept in D3 v3.x, but decided to abandon in D3 v4.x. To read more about that, have a look here: [*What Makes Software Good?*](https://medium.com/@mbostock/what-makes-software-good-943557f8a488) This is what he says:

> D3 2.0 introduced a change: appending to the enter selection would now copy entering elements into the update selection [...] D3 4.0 removes the magic of enter.append. (In fact, D3 4.0 removes the distinction between enter and normal selections entirely: there is now only one class of selection.)

This is a demo of your code using D3 v4.x. Nothing will show up, as you can see:

```js
const arr = [10, 20, 30]
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const lines = svg.selectAll('line').data(arr);
lines.enter().append('line');
lines.attr('x1', d => d)
  .attr('y1', d => d)
  .attr('x2', d => d + 40)
  .attr('y2', d => d + 20)
  .attr('stroke-width', 2)
  .attr("stroke", "black");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Now the exact same code, using D3 v3:

```js
const arr = [10, 20, 30]
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const lines = svg.selectAll('line').data(arr);
lines.enter().append('line');
lines.attr('x1', d => d)
  .attr('y1', d => d)
  .attr('x2', d => d + 40)
  .attr('y2', d => d + 20)
  .attr('stroke-width', 2)
  .attr("stroke", "black");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: This explains @Mark's answer. Thanks