# Update options in a drop-down menu based on another drop-down

Tags: d3.js

I'm attempting to set up two drop-down menus. The options in the menus are derived from a nested data set. The option selected in the first menu (group1) would determine the range of options available in the second menu (group2). The selection of an option in either the first or second menu should result in the chart updating.

The second menu selection isn't updating properly. When a selection is made in the group1 menu, the options in the group2 menu don't change, unless there are more options for the new menu selection than the previous menu selection, in which case extra options are appended to the group2 menu.

I'm not sure why this isn't working. My understanding of data binding/updating as applied to menu options is probably faulty. How can this be made to work?

I set up the menus like this:

```
// Set up the group1 selection menu
var select1 = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("select")
  .attr("class", "select")
  .attr("id", "select1")
  .on("change", function() { // If the group1 selection changes, change the options for group2 menu, and also update the graph?

    // Join the new options with previous data
    var options2 = d3.select("#select2").selectAll("option")
      .data(); // new options for group2 menu from the nested data

    // Remove exit selection
    options2.exit().remove(); 

    // Update selection
    options2.enter().append("option")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
  });

// Options for group1 selection menu
var options1 = d3.select("#select1")
  .data(); // Options for group1 from the nested data
  .append("option")
  .text(function (d) { return d; });

// Set up the initial group1 selection menu
var select2 = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("select")
  .attr("class", "select")
  .attr("id", "select2")
  .on("change", onchange);

// Initial options for group2 selection menu
var options2 = d3.select("#select2")
  .selectAll("option")
  .data() // initial options for group2
  .append("option")
  .text(function(d) { return d; });

function onchange() {
    // Make a graph with the selected data
}
```

A plunker is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/yFBHHrXYXgVdHvqfWDTU?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is D3 v4, not v3. In D3 v4, the *"magic"* of the enter selection, which copies the entering elements into the update selection, was removed.

So, you'll have to [merge](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_merge) the selections:

```
options2.enter()
    .append("option")
    .merge(options2)//merging here
    .text(function(d) {
      return d;
    });
```

For a better explanation, have a look at my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47032222/5768908).

Here is your plunker with that 1 line change only: http://plnkr.co/edit/APN2HqI1MY5KQb65qCHt?p=preview

Comment: Aha, thank you, that's a very helpful explanation and it makes perfect sense now.