# D3 update selections not updating text

Tags: d3.js

In the following code I'm trying to update the newly added p elements that d3 adds with the class person. I'm trying to show that d3 will add new p elements for the number of data points that exceed the number of elements already on the page. I am using D3 version 5.7.0.

D3 adds the new p elements but it will not add the person class to the new p elements. Only to the already existing elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="d3/d3.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            p {
                background: black;
                color: white;
                font-size: 30px;
                width: 150px;
                margin: 20px;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            .person {
                background: indigo;
                color: deeppink;
                font-size: 30px;
                width: 150px;
                margin: 20px;
                padding: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- no of elements = no of data points (update selection) -->
<!--         <p>Chair 1</p>
        <p>Chair 2</p>
        <p>Chair 3</p>
        <p>Chair 4</p> -->

        <!-- no of data points > no of elements (enter selection) -->
        <p>Chair 1</p>
        <p>Chair 2</p>
        <p>Chair 3</p>
        <p>Chair 4</p>

        <script>
/*             var myData = ["Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3", "Person 4"];

            d3.selectAll("p").data(myData)
                .text(function(d){return d;})
                .classed("person", true); */

            var myData = ["Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3", 
            "Person 4", "Person 5", "Person 6"];

            var update = d3.selectAll("p").data(myData);

            update.enter().append("p");

            update.text(function(d) { return d; }).classed("person", true);

        </script> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The update selection contains elements that existed at the time of selection - it does not include entered elements since they didn't exist when the selection was made (your update selection is empty). You either need to use .classed on the enter selection or use selection.merge(). This behavior is different than in v3.

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47032222/7106086

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myData = ["Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3", 
        "Person 4", "Person 5", "Person 6"];

var update = d3.selectAll("p").data(myData);
update.exit().remove(); // EXIT

update.enter().append("p").merge(update).text(function(d) { return d; }).classed("person", true);
```

Here the solution according to the D3 [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_merge)

Comment: d3v3 has a different behavior in this regard, in fact your fiddle should work without any pre-existing p tags: http://jsfiddle.net/h1c3zbgp/

Comment: Yes, Just now got it. what could be the reason for the above code it not working.

Comment: In v3 the enter selection was "magically" part of the update selection, in v4+ it was changed so that selections were immutable, the enter selection would remain separate of the update, to accommodate this the merge method was added. The code in the question is as expected: the update selection is empty because no elements were initially selected, everything is in the enter selection instead. Here is where the merge is used: `selection = selection.enter().merge(selection)`, now `selection` includes both entered and pre-existing(update selection elements) elements.

Comment: I quote the "magical" only because that's how Bostock refers to it when commenting on why he changed the behavior, here's the [article](https://medium.com/@mbostock/what-makes-software-good-943557f8a488), it might provide a bit more context

Comment: Thanks for the response CSMaverick. But in you stated I have at least 1 p tag. I have 4. That is the only difference. Your d3 code is exactly the same but yours worked. May you clarify?

Comment: Hi Rizzo, Did you observe the updated answer. It's the changes to your JS code alone I have used d3 merge function which return new selection with updated data.  this part -> update.exit().remove(); // EXIT


This method is commonly used to merge the enter and update selections after a data-join. After modifying the entering and updating elements separately, you can merge the two selections and perform operations on both without duplicate code.