# React + d3 force graph doesn't update position of last added node

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have a React component that lets me add nodes to a d3 force graph. Whenever I add a node its position in the underlying data is updated by the simulation, but its position is not updated visually until the next node is added. Is anybody able to spot why?

I've made a stripped back example that demonstrates the issue, which can also be seen [in this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kx99609k7v):

```
import React from "react";
import shortid from "shortid";
import * as d3 from "d3";

const WIDTH = 500;
const HEIGHT = 500;

class Graph extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nodes: [],
      value: shortid(),
    };
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };

  handleAddNode = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const newNodes = [...this.state.nodes, { id: this.state.value }];

    this.setState({ nodes: newNodes, value: shortid() });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.initialise(this.state.nodes);
    this.draw(this.state.nodes);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.draw(this.state.nodes);
  }

  initialise = nodes => {
    const container = d3
      .select(this.svg)
      .attr("width", WIDTH)
      .attr("height", HEIGHT)
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "container")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + WIDTH / 2 + "," + HEIGHT / 2 + ")");

    container.append("g").attr("class", "nodes");

    this.simulation = d3
      .forceSimulation(nodes)
      .alphaDecay(0.2)
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().strength(1))
      .on("tick", this.ticked);
  };

  draw = nodes => {
    this.nodesSelection = d3
      .select(".nodes")
      .selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes);

    this.nodesSelection
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("data-id", d => d.id)
      .style("fill", "red")
      .attr("r", 5);

    this.simulation.nodes(nodes);
    this.simulation.alpha(1).restart();

    console.log(nodes);
  };

  ticked = () => {
    this.nodesSelection.attr("cx", d => d.x).attr("cy", d => d.y);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="c-graph-container">
        <form className="c-node-creator">
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <button onClick={this.handleAddNode}>Add</button>
        </form>
        <svg ref={svg => (this.svg = svg)} className=".c-graph" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Graph;
```

Comment: Your update selection (`this.nodeSelection`) doesn't include nodes that are in the enter selection (`this.nodeSelection.enter()`). Since selections are immutable, the update selection doesn't contain the entered nodes after entering unless you re-select or use a merge. For example: https://codesandbox.io/s/6lv31znk0k. See also, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47032222/7106086

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As correctly pointed out by Andrew in the comments the update selection (this.nodesSelection) doesn't include nodes that are in the enter selection (this.nodesSelection.enter()). Since selections are immutable, the update selection doesn't contain the entered nodes after entering unless you re-select or use a merge.

So the fix in my case is to change the selection line to:

```
this.nodesSelection = this.nodesSelection
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("data-id", d => d.id)
  .style("fill", "red")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .merge(this.nodesSelection);
```