# Missing slices after updating a d3v3 donut chart to d3v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3 in general, so please bear with me. I did my best to research a fix for a transitional d3 Donut chart that I need to work with d3v4, but to no avail.  The idea originally came from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/DDDDDanica/69458589f62093d8ec5c6b2ea3a70b6d/c2ba2bc693989cb0c749c133201662ec4eec1f16) and I already know [this chart](https://codepen.io/patrol71/pen/oJqxLr) displays just fine for me with d3v3.  After updating to make the same chart work in v4, which can be found [here](https://codepen.io/patrol71/pen/OrvNvm), it doesn't display correctly and I'm stumped.  I already searched for an answer, but unable to find what I need.  I thought the problem was due to interpolation, but not sure. Any help will be deeply appreciated and thanks in advance.

My code for the d3v4 chart is also below.

```js
datasetOption1 = [
 {label: "Tropical Cyclone", value: 592319},
 {label: "Drought", value: 76713},
 {label: "Flooding", value: 36891}];

datasetOption2 = [
 {label: "Tropical Cyclone", value: 1992},
 {label: "Drought", value: 2416},
 {label: "Severe Storm", value: 498},
 {label: "Winter Storm", value: 457}];

 d3.selectAll("input").on("change", selectDataset); 
  
 var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .append("g")

 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "slices");
 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "labelName");
 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "lines");

 var width = 480,
  height = 225, 
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

 var pie = d3.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
   return d.value;
  });

 var arc = d3.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.4);

 var outerArc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

 var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

 var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
 
 change(datasetOption1);
 
  d3.select("input[value=\"option1\"]").property("checked", true); 
  
 function selectDataset()
 {
  var value = this.value;
  if (value == "option1")
  {
   change(datasetOption1);
  }
  else
  {
   change(datasetOption2);
  }
 }  
  
 function change(data) {
  /* ------- PIE SLICES -------*/
  var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
   .data(pie(data), function(d){ 
    return d.data.label });

  slice.enter()
   .insert("path")
   .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.label); })
    .style("opacity", 0.7)
   .attr("class", "slice");

  slice
   .transition().duration(1000)
   .attrTween("d", function(d) {
    var node = this;
    node._current = node._current || d;
    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(node._current, d);
    node._current = interpolate(0);
    return function(t) {
     return arc(interpolate(t));
    };
   })
  slice
   .on("mousemove", function(d){
    tooltip.style("left", d3.event.pageX+10+"px");
    tooltip.style("top", d3.event.pageY-25+"px");
    tooltip.style("display", "inline-block");
    tooltip.html((d.data.label)+"<br>"+(d.data.value));
   });
  slice
   .on("mouseout", function(d){
    tooltip.style("display", "none");
   });

  slice.exit()
   .remove();

  /* ------- TEXT LABELS -------*/

  var text = svg.select(".labelName").selectAll("text")
   .data(pie(data), function(d){ return d.data.label });

  text.enter()
   .append("text")
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .text(function(d) {
    return (d.data.label+": "+d.value);
   });

  function midAngle(d){
   return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2;
  }

  text
   .transition().duration(1000)
   .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
    var node = this;
    node._current = node._current || d;
    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(node._current, d);
    node._current = interpolate(0);
    return function(t) {
     var d2 = interpolate(t);
     var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
     pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
     return "translate("+ pos +")";
    };
   })
   .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d){
    var node = this;
    node._current = node._current || d;
    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(node._current, d);
    node._current = interpolate(0);
    return function(t) {
     var d2 = interpolate(t);
     return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start":"end";
    };
   })
   .text(function(d) {
    return (d.data.label+": "+d.value);
   });

  text.exit().remove();

  /* ------- SLICE TO TEXT POLYLINES -------*/
  var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline")
   .data(pie(data), function(d){ return d.data.label });

  polyline.enter()
   .append("polyline");

  polyline.transition().duration(1000)
   .attrTween("points", function(d){
    var node = this;
    node._current = node._current || d;
    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(node._current, d);
    node._current = interpolate(0);
    return function(t) {
     var d2 = interpolate(t);
     var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
     pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
     return [arc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2), pos];
    };
   });

  polyline.exit()
   .remove();
 };
```

```css
 body {
   font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   width: 960px;
   height: 500px;
   position: relative;
 }

 svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }

 path.slice{
  stroke-width:2px;
 }

 polyline{
  opacity: .3;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  fill: none;
 }

 .labelValue{
  font-size: 60%;
  opacity: .5;  
 }

 .toolTip {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 15px #888888;
  color: black;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
 }
 
 text {
   font: 12px sans-serif;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <form>
    <label><input type="radio" name="dataset" id="dataset" value="option1"> Option 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="dataset" id="dataset" value="option2"> Option 2</label>
  </form>
  <br>
  
</body>
```

Comment: You need to merge selections (enter and update) - you only ever update the existing elements (which is the two common slices), every other change you add one or two unique slices which are entered and never updated (they exit before they update). This is also why the slices don't draw on load: you enter but don't transition them (enter selections are not part of the initial selection which is immutable). See here: https://jsfiddle.net/uaq7s3fg/ , which addresses the missing slices (but not the initial transitions). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47032051/7106086) question might help.

Comment: Merging appears to be the fix.  I applied the same updates for the label text and polylines.  Thanks so much, Andrew....you're a lifesaver!!!