# d3v4 pie chart with horizontal labels

Tags: d3.js

I've got some old pie chart code with nice horizontal labels -- and I am porting from v3 to v4. But my labels/pointer are no longer working?

I am not getting any errors so not sure why the old pointer/label code isn't being applied -- is there a more efficient way of doing this now?

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/cybsgtq8/2/

old label and pointer implementation

```
                //__labels  
                var labels = labels.selectAll("text")
                    .data(piedata);

                labels.enter()
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")


                labels
                    .attr("x", function(d) {
                        var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
                        d.cx = Math.cos(a) * (ir+((r-ir)/2));
                        return d.x = Math.cos(a) * (r + 20);
                    })
                    .attr("y", function(d) {
                        var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
                        d.cy = Math.sin(a) * (ir+((r-ir)/2));
                        return d.y = Math.sin(a) * (r + 20);
                    })
                    .text(function(d) {
                        return d.data.label; 
                    })
                    .each(function(d) {
                        var bbox = this.getBBox();
                        d.sx = d.x - bbox.width/2 - 2;
                        d.ox = d.x + bbox.width/2 + 2;
                        d.sy = d.oy = d.y + 5;
                    })
                    .transition()
                        .duration(300)

                labels
                    .transition()
                    .duration(300)      

                labels.exit().remove();
                //__labels


                //__pointers
                pointers.append("defs").append("marker")
                    .attr("id", "circ")
                    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
                    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
                    .attr("refX", 3)
                    .attr("refY", 3)
                    .append("circle")
                    .attr("cx", 3)
                    .attr("cy", 3)
                    .attr("r", 3);

                var pointers = pointers.selectAll("path.pointer")
                    .data(piedata);

                pointers.enter()
                    .append("path")
                    .attr("class", "pointer")
                    .style("fill", "none")
                    .style("stroke", "black")
                    .attr("marker-end", "url(#circ)");

                pointers
                    .attr("d", function(d) {
                        if(d.cx > d.ox) {
                            return "M" + d.sx + "," + d.sy + "L" + d.ox + "," + d.oy + " " + d.cx + "," + d.cy;
                        } else {
                            return "M" + d.ox + "," + d.oy + "L" + d.sx + "," + d.sy + " " + d.cx + "," + d.cy;
                        }
                    })
                    .transition()
                        .duration(300)

                pointers
                    .transition()
                    .duration(300)      

                pointers.exit().remove();

                //__pointers
```

-- my new jsfiddle with new code
https://jsfiddle.net/ef0vcz2g/1/

[image]
^ whats happened.

Comment: In d3v4+ an enter selection is no longer automatically merged with the original selection, instead selections are immutable. So in your code, `labels` is always an empty selection even after `.enter()`, in d3v3, `.enter()` would modify the original selection to include the entered components. See  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47032051/7106086) question for more info. Here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kyxcq2bu/) which uses a variable (`labelEnter`) to hold the entered elements. Mike Bostock has an explanation somewhere, I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: -- you able to write this as an answer -- keen to see the problem code specifically -- whats the change ?

Comment: what about writing a legend too - is it a same problem?