# Why my graphs are not showing up in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

[This](http://bl.ocks.org/lmatteis/73ce86ae3ce3332035c9c2829a94b7c1) example was on the v3 version so I tried to update it to v5 by debugging line by line.

This is my version:
https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/c67330badd3f9063a214135bc7f98629

I ain't getting any error. It is just not showing any graph (bar and bubble). I assume it is due to x-axis and y-axis setting part but not able to find out the error.

**Update:**

I can see these lines are not working:

```
rects
    .on('click', function (d) { dimension.filter(d.key); dispatch.update(); reset.style('display', 'block') })
  .transition(t)
    .attr('class', function(d) {
      log("bar-bar:", d.key);

     return 'bar bar--' + (d.key == 'female' ? 'negative' : 'positive'); })
    .attr('x', function(d) { return x(d.key); })
    .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
    .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr('height', function(d) { 
      log("ht:",height - y(d.value));

      return height - y(d.value); })
```

Found the error in this line:

```
var rects = g.selectAll('rect')
```

But how to solve it.

Comment: in d3v3, entering added elements to the original selection, here `rects`. In d3v4+ selections are immutable, the update selection `rects` remains only a selection of those elements that existed at the time of selection, even after entering. You'll need to merge enter and update, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47032222/7106086).

Comment: Didn't work for me    `rects.enter().append('rect').merge(rects);`

Comment: `var rects = g.selectAll('rect')
        .data(group.all()); `  <-------- this gives me array of length 2 but empty. I compared both the d3 and d5 version. Theit otputs are different.